# Binding data from ClipboardWatcher

Tags: wpf, data-binding, clipboard

I'm use  Willy-Kimura / SharpClipboard nuget to retrieve data from clipboard.
Data is returned to string Pc, but still not showing up in TextBox.

**TestClass:**

```
public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SharpClipboard clipboard = new SharpClipboard();

    public TestClass()
    {
        clipboard.ClipboardChanged += ClipboardChanged;
    }

    Private void ClipboardChanged(Object sender, ClipboardChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ContentType == SharpClipboard.ContentTypes.Text)
        {
            Pc = clipboard.ClipboardText;
        }
    }

    private string _pc;
    public string Pc
    {
        get { return _pc; }
        set { if (_pc != value) { _pc = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Pc)); } }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Pc, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="IP/Netbios" Style="{StaticResource MainTextBox}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

What is wrong with binding in Pc? I have many another binds in solution and they are works fine. Rest binding I calls using icommand. Data is being obtained only once from methods. But here is something obtained automatically.

**Update - DataContext**

```
private readonly TestClass testClass;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    testClass = new TestClass();
    DataContext = new TestClass(DialogCoordinator.Instance);
}
```

My DataContext. I'm not sure it is good all here. 2x new TestClass - I'm worried about TestClass instance here. DialogCoordinator.Instance is from MahApps.Metro.

Comment: Looks fine to me at first glance. Make sure `DataContext` is set correctly and `e.ContentType == SharpClipboard.ContentTypes.Text` is returning `true`.

Comment: @KeithStein updated Code with DataContext

Comment: If it still doesn't work with the `DataContext` set, try testing with breakpoints to see what methods actually get called. You may need to post a full reproducible example for others to test with.